# BIND Reverse DNS Ignoring out-of-zone data

Tags: centos, dns, bind

I have a simple, single-address reverse DNS PTR for `10.142.0.2` to `gbox.example.com` record set up like so:

```
# cat /var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db

$ORIGIN .
$TTL 1D
0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.  IN  SOA gbox.example.com. dnsadmin.example.com. (
                                2018111401  ;
                                12h         ;
                                5m          ;
                                1w          ;
                                3h          ;
                                )

                        NS      gbox.example.com.

$ORIGIN 0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.
2                       PTR     gbox.example.com.
```

and when I run:

```
#  named-checkzone 2.0.142.10.in-addr.arpa /var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db
/var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db:5: ignoring out-of-zone data (0.142.10.in-addr.arpa)
zone 2.0.142.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone 2.0.142.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: has no NS records
zone 2.0.142.10.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
# named-checkzone 10.142.0.2 /var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db
/var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db:5: ignoring out-of-zone data (0.142.10.in-addr.arpa)
/var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db:16: ignoring out-of-zone data (2.0.142.10.in-addr.arpa)
zone 10.142.0.2/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone 10.142.0.2/IN: has no NS records
zone 10.142.0.2/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

And for the life of me I can't figure out what is going on here.

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
$bind -v
BIND 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-61.el7_5.1 (Extended Support Version)
```

**EDIT:** I tried an alternate syntax version of the zone file with no change:

```
# cat /var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db

$ORIGIN 0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 1D
@  IN  SOA gbox.example.com. dnsadmin.example.com. (
                                2018111401  ;
                                12h         ;
                                5m          ;
                                1w          ;
                                3h          ;
                                )

                        NS      gbox.example.com.

2                       PTR     gbox.example.com.
```

**EDIT 2:** Integrated it into `named.conf`:

```
zone "0.142.10.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    allow-transfer { none; };
    notify  no;
    file "/var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db";
};
```

and I still get the same error with `named-checkzone`

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean? I'm not currently loading it anywhere, since it doesn't work in the test.

Comment: `0.0.10.in-addr.arpa` should probably have a `.` after the "arpa" - `0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.`

Comment: Added the `.` and no change. Updating question.

Comment: I am not loading it into named.conf yet. I am testing it with named-checkzone before adding it to named.conf because I don't want it loading a broken zone.  Is there another portion of named.conf that would help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created the zone '0.142.10.in-addr.arpa', so you have to check that one:

```
named-checkzone 0.142.10.in-addr.arpa /var/named/zones/0.142.10.in-addr.arpa.db
```