# BIND9 DNS zone file check reveals "ignoring out-of-zone data"

Tags: dns, bind9

I am running a DNS and DCHP service on a local server (Raspberry on Stretch).

When checking the zone files, I get:

```
# [2019-02-03 10:32] maxg@rpiserver /etc/bind/zones $
named-checkzone rpiserver argylecourt.org.db
argylecourt.org.db:22: ignoring out-of-zone data (argylecourt.org)
argylecourt.org.db:23: ignoring out-of-zone data (argylecourt.org)
zone rpiserver/IN: has no NS records
zone rpiserver/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

This is the contents of the argylecourt.org.db zone file:

```
; Host-to-IP Address DNS Pointers for argylecourt.org
; Note: The extra “.” at the end of the domain names are important.
;
; $ORIGIN .
$TTL    86400      ; 1 day
; rpiserver.argylecourt.org. IN SOA rpiserver.argylecourt.org. hostmaster.argylecourt.org. (
@ IN SOA rpiserver.argylecourt.org. hostmaster.argylecourt.org. (
        2019020203 ; serial
                8H ; refresh
                4H ; retry
                2W ; expire
                1D ; minimum
)

; NS indicates that rpiserver is the name server on argylecourt.org
; MX indicates that rpiserver is (also) the mail server on argylecourt.org
argylecourt.org. IN NS rpiserver.argylecourt.org.
argylecourt.org. IN MX 10 rpiserver.argylecourt.org.

;$ORIGIN argylecourt.org.

; Set the address for localhost.argylecourt.org
;localhost      IN      A       127.0.0.1
;localhost      IN      A       192.168.1.7
rpiserver       IN      A       192.168.1.7
www             IN      CNAME   argylecourt.org
```

I also have errors in the reverse zone:

```
# [2019-02-03 10:43] maxg@rpiserver /etc/bind/zones $
named-checkzone rpiserver rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
zone rpiserver/IN: NS 'rpiserver' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone rpiserver/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

... which has this contents:

```
$TTL    86400      ; 1 day
; IP Address-to-Host DNS Pointers for the 192.168.1 subnet
@ IN SOA rpiserver.argylecourt.org. hostmaster.argylecourt.org. (
        2019020203 ; serial
                8H ; refresh
                4H ; retry
                2W ; expire
                1D ; minimum
)

; define the authoritative name server
;       IN      NS      rpiserver.argylecourt.org.
        IN      NS      rpiserver.
```

[update 1] Have just read: [BIND Reverse DNS Ignoring out-of-zone data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481518/bind-reverse-dns-ignoring-out-of-zone-data?rq=1) -- which resulted in 0 errors when applied to my situation.

```
# [2019-02-03 10:46] maxg@rpiserver /etc/bind/zones $
named-checkzone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2019020203
OK
# [2019-02-03 10:52] maxg@rpiserver /etc/bind/zones $
named-checkzone argylecourt.org argylecourt.org.db
zone argylecourt.org/IN: loaded serial 2019020203
OK
```

[update 2] restarting bind9 results in:

```
# [2019-02-03 11:19] maxg@rpiserver /etc/bind/zones $
sudo service bind9 status
● bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-03 11:19:40 AEST; 22s ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
  Process: 5661 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rndc stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5667 (named)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bind9.service
           └─5667 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind

Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: managed-keys-zone: journal file is out of date: removing journal file
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 648
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2017061507
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: zone argylecourt.org/IN: loaded serial 2017061536
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: all zones loaded
Feb 03 11:19:40 rpiserver named[5667]: running
```

Where do I need to look to fix this problem?

Comment: You are missing at least one period after a FQDN.  Without a final period, Bind assumes that you are referencing a host within the domain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started digging further when I realised the old serial number.
I looked up cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local, which pointed to [file "/var/lib/bind/argylecourt.org.db";]
... while I was updating /etc/bind/zones/argylecourt.org.db

Comment: I came across this question while researching a different issue (and upvoted it because it was well researched). It would be a good idea to accept your own (this) answer to indicate to other visitors that the issue was resolved. It's also the kind of issue that every sysadmin has at some stage.

Answer (score 1):

It's the full stops - in the first file the final line needs to be:

```
www             IN      CNAME   argylecourt.org.
```

Without a full stop on the end it'll append the domain name again.

In your reverse zone the penultimate line is correct and should be commented out, the final line with rpiserver. will try and find something called rpiserver as a top-level (no domain after it) - you can also just try removing the full stop but I would use the penultimate one.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had before... while this validates as OK; when I restart my bind9 it still tells me to have loaded a config with a serial from 2017. See [update 2]

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're editing the zones files in the right directory, not using bind-chroot for example? I'm not aware of BIND doing any caching of local zones (other than loading them into RAM maybe).

Comment: No, I am not sure... however, as far as I can tell, what I did seems to work. I also temporarily removed the files in /etc/... and restarted bind, and it loaded its config clearly from /var/...